# HttpTransportSE.call method returns NullPointerException frequently

Tags: android, web-services, android-ksoap2

I connect to a webservice to download master data for my app. So, in a single download the app will need to call the webservice a no of times with different indexes.

During this, *HttpTransportSE.call* method returns *NullPointerException* for some indexes sometimes, otherwise it works fine.

My calling function is :

```
public String SoapAction(String[] values){

String[] data = new String[] { "CompanyID", "Username", "Password", "indexNo", "DataString","lDate" };

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

for(int i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();
  property.setName(data[i]);
  property.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
  property.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
  property.setValue(values[i]); 

  request.addProperty(property);
}

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

try{
  HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
  http.debug = true;
  System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");

  http.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
}catch (IOException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();         
  return "serverError";
} catch (XmlPullParserException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
  return "serverError";     
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();          
  return "serverError";
}

SoapPrimitive resultString = null;

try{
  resultString = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
}catch (SoapFault e) {
  e.printStackTrace();          
  return "serverError";
}

if(resultString != null){
  return resultString.toString();
} else {
  return "serverError";
}
}
```

I did quite a bit of googling, but couldn't find a solution

Here's the stacktrace:
02-06 14:01:14.136: W/System.err(1504): java.lang.NullPointerException

02-06 14:01:14.136: W/System.err(1504):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.getResponseProperties(ServiceConnectionSE.java:85)

02-06 14:01:14.136: W/System.err(1504):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:167)

02-06 14:01:14.136: W/System.err(1504):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:96)

02-06 14:29:50.026: W/System.err(1504):     at com.c2info.engine.WebServiceConnection.SoapAction(WebServiceConnection.java:49)

02-06 14:29:50.026: W/System.err(1504):     at com.c2info.engine.DownloadData.downloadTasks(DownloadData.java:800)

02-06 14:29:50.026: W/System.err(1504):     at com.c2info.engine.DownloadData$3.run(DownloadData.java:187)

Comment: Did you see the log? Please, give me stacktrace of the thrown exception.

Comment: e.toString() shows java.land.NullPointerException. Im trying to get the stacktrace of the exception but the error isn't showing up now, as i said, it only happens at times. Im trying again

Comment: in your catch area please add raw e.printStackTrace(); and give me the stack. It will be in your LogCat

Comment: Is it all the stack trace?? Or there are other raws, but you didn't include them?

Comment: I have added the complete stacktrace

Comment: I think, you have not set your properties to envelope? so that you have NullPointer, th envelope is null, or it's property field is null. You can try to set property as i explained in my answer using PropertyInfo class.

Comment: Did I solve your problem?

Comment: @JunR No, it still persists. Any other suggestion would be helpful

Comment: if you post the full project somewhere and give me a link, I'll look at your code and debug it.

Comment: @JunR I have added the whole sending function, after making the changes you recommended

Comment: could u give me all used constants? SOAP_ACTION and other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing some research, I found out that it happens when the server is busy and by the time the server processes your request, the HttpTransportSE call method times out. The default time-out values in 20s. So, to overcome this, :

- Set a suitable time-out value

  > HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL, 30000);
- Enclose the http.call method in a while loop and retry till 'N' no of times till you get a valid response

Answer (score 2):

I never add the properties like your

```
request.addProperty("data", "value");
```

Try this:

```
PropertyInfo property = new PropertyInfo();
{
    property.name = "data";
    property.setNamespace(NAMESPACE);
    property.type = PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS;
    property.setValue("value"); 
}
request.addProperty(property);
```

Also try to use

```
SoapEnvelope.VER11
```

instead of VER12

and add raw

```
envelope.implicitTypes = true;
```

And did you add this permission in AndroidMAnifest.xml?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Is thr any problem in using request.addProperty("data", "value") ?

Comment: and whats the advantage of VER11 over VER12 ?

Comment: It's just versions of envelope. If you have NUllPointer in properties: maybe wrong property, or try downgrade version of envelope